# Need to view folders from memory card for android application

Tags: android, view, directory

I need to create a application like to view folders from the mobiles memory card... is it possible to create views like contacts. you already knew that there is a in build "intent" method to view contacts from our phone in android.. i would like to make same to show all folders from memory card ?? can any one give suggestions ???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no native intent for browsing file like a folder explorer.

You can write you own using `ListView`  with something like

`File file[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();`

or you can also reusing a third-party library like this one: 
http://openintents.org/en/filemanager

Never tried but looks good to me!

Comment: hi francesco... thank u for quick reply...its looks cool..lets try it

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to leave a green mark on my answer in it works for you